# Xcode 10.1 Can't Find or Create iOS Simulators

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

For context I am working with a fresh install of macOS Mojave and a fresh install of Xcode 10.1.

The first thing I noticed was I only had the option of 
[Generic iOS Device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/caknc.png) from the simulator drop down list. It seems Xcode did not download any iOS simulators with it like I thought it was supposed to.

So I went looking in the [simulator list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvLYg.png), and it was empty. So the next logical step is to try and create a simulator. Where I only found the ability to [download simulators](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxNWp.png). So I [downloaded four simulators](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHV9d.png) and went back to try and create them. Nothing changed, I could still only download simulators. I wasn't about to select a device or a simulator.

I have tried restarting Xcode, the OS, and reinstalling Xcode none of which have worked. I have tried deleting DerivedData, but that didn't work either. So, I am now at a point where my Google searches are just turning up the same tired answers, and I am getting no where.

**Edit**
Here is the error message I get if I try to build anything, if it helps.

```
2018-12-07 05:49:31.315 ibtoold[1550:71807] Error 
Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=61 "Connection refused" UserInfo=
{NSLocalizedDescription=CoreSimulator.framework was changed while the 
process was running. This is not a supported configuration and can occur 
if Xcode.app was updated while the process was running. Service name 
((null)) does not match expected service name 

(com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService).} 2018-12-07 05:49:31.315 
ibtoold[1550:71807] Failed to load CoreSimulatorService. Access to 
simulator services will not be available. Error=Error 
Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=61 "Connection refused" UserInfo=
{NSLocalizedDescription=CoreSimulator.framework was changed while the 
process was running. This is not a supported configuration and can occur 
if Xcode.app was updated while the process was running. Service name 
((null)) does not match expected service name 

(com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService).} 2018-12-07 05:49:31.400 
ibtoold[1550:71824] CoreSimulatorService connection became invalid. 
Simulator services will no longer be available.
```

Comment: What do your schemes look like?

Comment: @Dare You are going to need to be a bit more specific about what you are looking for?

Comment: Quit Xcode, Safari, and Console.app. Then kill the process `com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService`. It should restart then the default simulators should be created.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. I tried each and everything that Google has said. But didn't find any solution. So, finally, I removed all the Xcode from the system and update the mac os with Mojave 10.14(earlier it was 10.13). Then I reinstall the Xcode 10.1. This time Xcode asked the permission to install extra components. After installation of these components, I am able to see the list of all the simulators.

The problem, what I have observed, was that there was no device present in the core simulator folder under the library/developer. Please check if this folder present or not on the following path: Users/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices.

Comment: Ultimately it came down to uninstalling everything, and making sure there was absolutely nothing left behind. Then reinstalling everything. If I remember correctly I might have had to do this a couple times.